# `npx .` does not execute the bin script from my local package

Tags: node.js, node-modules, local, npx, volta

Sadly I was not able to find input to my problem anywhere on the internet. I am currently dabbling around with npx and want to debug my bin script before pushing it to a registry. What I found out is that it should be possible to execute the bin script of you local package.json by running `npx .`.

My bin script is very simple at this point and only consists of the following

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log("Awesome Command");
```

If I do this however I only see the a short (understandable as it is only a local package at this point) loading animation and then nothing. I would expect my console.log to show up.

If I run the script directly throgh `node index.js` it logs as expected.

When I look at my local `.npm/_npx` directory everything looks as I would expect it to. I have one entry with a package.json having a dependency pointing to my local file.

I am runnning node through volta and first suspected that to have something to do with it but if I run `/usr/bin/env node` the node repl opens with the version installed by volta. So I think this might not be the root cause for my issue.

I am a bit desperate at this point and would appreciate any help or even input on the matter what could be wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.